# Running javascript component in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to use the Odometer from https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer as a component within Svelte.

However, I'm seeing the error below.

[image]

**Svelte Component**

```
<script>
//      Trying to use Odometer from https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer within Svelte
//      Have added export Odometer to js from Github in Odometer.js component above
    
    import Odometer from 'Odometer.js';
    
    const el

    onMount(async () => {
        el = document.querySelector('.odometer');
        const od = new Odometer({
            el: el,
            value: 333555,
            format: '',
            theme: 'digital'
         });
    }
    $: od.update(555)

</script>

<section>
    <div id="odometer" class="odometer">
    </div>
</section>
  
<style>

</style>
```

**Amended Javascript**

I have added an export function as below to the js in Github (http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js).

```
export function Odometer () {
```

replaces first line of...

```
(function() {
    var COUNT_FRAMERATE...
```

**Includes**

The regular includes are below.  I have included just the css in my index file.

```
    <!-- Odometer includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css" />
    <script src="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>
```

Is this the right way to do this?

**Svelte Repl**

https://svelte.dev/repl/5586442696454dbda9a4efd4853556db?version=3.52.0

Comment: Please include your code *in* the question and not just link to it. Questions (and answers) should be self-contained.

Comment: You just need to wrap the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API) stuff in `onMount` I would have written a full answer, but the svelte repl doesn't like the `odometer.js` file so I'm settling for a comment. [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/d2beab176f004270a739111320de8c5b?version=3.52.0)

Comment: @Zachiah: An answer does not need a working REPL link, nor does it need any code at all. All that matters is that it answers the question/problem.

Comment: Updated to include code within post

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- You cannot just `export function` at the beginning of the file. The function is immediately invoked and it defines exports/global variables at the very end. You would have to patch that differently:

  1. Add `export const Odometer = (function() { ...` at the top
  2. Replace the part with the exports with a return statement.
     This:

     ```js
      if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], function() {
          return Odometer;
        });
      } else if (typeof exports === !'undefined') {
        module.exports = Odometer;
      } else {
        window.Odometer = Odometer;
      }
     ```

     To:

     ```js
     return Odometer;
     ```
- If you use the `digital` theme, you have to import the stylesheet for that, not `car`.
- It's a named export, so it has to be imported as:

  ```js
  import { Odometer } from './Odometer.js';
  ```
- You should not query the DOM in Svelte. Either use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this) on elements, which become usable in/after [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount) or [use actions](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action). Would recommend the latter, as you can use them directly without additional imports:

  ```js
   let value = 555;
   let od = null;
   $: if (od) od.update(value);

   function addOdometer(node) { 
       od = new Odometer({
           el: node,
           value: 333555,
           format: '',
           theme: 'digital'
       });
   }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="odometer" use:addOdometer />
  ```

[REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244871/running-javascript-component-in-svelte#74244871)

(Would not recommend using unmaintained and archived libraries, though.)